# Get document embed URL for document in skydrive using Skydrive API

Tags: excel, api, embed, token, onedrive

I'm automating the embebbing of documents in my blog addon. I can upload an excel file to skydrive but to embed the document I should proccess manually the file in Skydrive and get the embed URL.
What's the way to get this embed URL via skydrive API?
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft appears to document this functionality here:

[Working with Microsoft SkyDrive folders and files -> Getting links to folders and files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531.aspx#file_links)